# Nodejs: how to create video from images?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

How can you create a video from given images in Node.js?
I tried using the `ffmpeg` npm module but it won't work for me, and I also tried using the [`videoshow`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videoshow) npm module and that also did not work for me.

Can anyone suggest how to create video from images and also give me some basic code to run?

Answer (score 4):

Using ffmpeg directly is challenging and I don't recommend it. Instead, I do recommend the videoshow npm that you reference. It too can be tricky, but after plenty of fiddling, I was able to get videoshow working within our project nicely.

Here is my code (just fill in your own paths and it should work)

```
var videoshow = require('videoshow')

var secondsToShowEachImage = 1
var finalVideoPath = '/whatever_path_works_for_you'

// setup videoshow options
var videoOptions = {
  fps: 24,
  transition: false,
  videoBitrate: 1024 ,
  videoCodec: 'libx264', 
  size: '640x640',
  outputOptions: ['-pix_fmt yuv420p'],
  format: 'mp4' 
}

// array of images to make the 'videoshow' from
var images = [
  {path: path1, loop: secondsToShowEachImage}, 
  {path: path2, loop: secondsToShowEachImage}, 
  ...etc  
]

videoshow(images, videoOptions)
.save(finalVideoPath)
.on('start', function (command) { 
  console.log('encoding ' + finalVideoPath + ' with command ' + command) 
})
.on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  return Promise.reject(new Error(err)) 
})
.on('end', function (output) {
  // do stuff here when done
})
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12665975)

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​How this isn't an answer? I think it's trying to answer the question instead of *critique or request clarification from the asker*.

Comment: @KevinGuan My first draft had more questions than answers and so he was right to critique. However, my most recent edit should provide a solid answer to the question.

Comment: @world: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Ah, got it.

Comment: How we can get a hls video instead of .mp4?

Comment: videoshow is intended for making slideshows, not videos. The loop option determines how many seconds each image is shown, where the minimum value seems to be 0.1, meaning your video can be 10 fps at most.